# Is it possible to have multiples queries on same collection in 1 function in mongodb using node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

```
const maincount = await User.find({ isaccepted: 'false' }, { id: 1 })
            .sort({ _id: 1 })
            .limit(1)
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
const urcount = await User.findOne({ name: 'prajakta' }, { id: 1 }).catch(err => console.log(err))
res.send({ $subtract: [ urcount.id, maincount.id ] })
```

How can I subtract the maincount and urcount values?

Comment: Yes, `Collection.find({
    key: value,key:value,key:value
  }, {
    //projections
  })`

Comment: I want to subtract the ids of the two? Eg Maincount=3, and urcount =13 so the result shoule be 10

Comment: what does that mean, subtracting id means what, share the required output

Comment: if I run the two queries individually, i get maincount = 3 and urCount =13 and I want the output = 10 (i.e. I want to subtract the counts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just merge the conditions.

```js
try {
   await User.find({ name: 'prajakta', accepted: 'false' }, { id: 1 })
      .sort(...)
      .limit(...)
} catch (e) {
   // TODO: error handling...
}
```

Comment: I want to subtract the result of the two individual queries. First find() query gives result as Id=3 and second findOne() query gives Id=13, I want to subtract the two ids

Comment: Please, formulate clear questions next time. If you need to subtract the IDs (without storing the result in MongoDB, but returning  it as response), you can just subtract the two values.

Comment: Hey sorry for the inconvenience, but can we call two find() queries in 1 function. The result I get after the above query gives '13,null'

Comment: Do you need to store the result in MongoDB or only returning it as response?

Comment: Just returning the response

Comment: Then, you can do `res.json({ value: urcount.id - maincount.id });` like a regular subtraction, no need to use MongoDB operators.

Answer (score 0):

**You can Follow This Code**

```
let doc=await User.find({
  $and:[
    {
     name: 'prajakta'
    },
    {
      accepted: 'false'
     },
     {
       id: 1 
     }
]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You may find [`$facet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) useful for this in an aggregation framework. The two facets will hold the results from the two queries and you can then 
do the subtraction in the later stages of the aggregate pipeline.

Take for instance the following approach:

```
const pipeline = [
    { '$facet': {
        'maincount': [
            { '$match': { isaccepted: 'false' } },
            { '$sort': { '_id': 1 } },
            { '$limit': 1 }
        ],
        'urcount': [
            { '$match': { name: 'prajakta' } },
            { '$limit': 1 }
        ]
    } },
    { '$project': { 
        'diff': {
            '$subtract': [
                { '$arrayElemAt': ['$urcount.id', 0] },
                { '$arrayElemAt': ['$maincount.id', 0] }
            ]
        }
    } }
]

const result = await User.aggregate(pipeline).exec()
console.log(result[0])
```